# docker compose redis with .net core integration test

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, redis

I'm trying to run integration test with redis in docker. I have .yml file setup as follows but when I run docker compose up it doesnt show the test results or doesnt run the dockerfile at all, but it responds with success and shows the redis and test container are created. The redis container stays up but the test exits quickly. What do I have to change to view the test results or even to check if its running the tests?

```
version: '3.4'

services:  
  redis-service:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "6379:6379" 
  test-service:
    image:  ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}redistest
    depends_on:
      - redis-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tests/RedisTest/Dockerfile
```

And here is the docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["tests/RedisTest/RedisTest.csproj", "tests/RedisTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "tests/RedisTest/RedisTest.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet test "/src/tests/RedisTest/RedisTest.csproj" -c Release --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.trx"
```

Comment: The test container shuts down when the tests are complete, so that's working as expected. To see how the tests went, you can find the exited container using `docker ps -a` and then view the logs using `docker logs <container-name>`.

Comment: @HansKilian thanks for your response. The log is empty and I dont even think its reading the dockerfile on docker compose up, because its not complaining when I pass a file that doesnt exist. When I do docker compose build it runs the dockerfile but since it skips the redis image the tests fail.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem

1. Remove image:  ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}redistest from the test-service since we are not building from an image rather from the docker file
2. The most important one: I was stupidly using RUN and CMD interchangeably. Replacing RUN command with CMD will run the test after both containers are started.

Comment: I would add that only the last command in the test docker file should be CMD, and it's important because it executes at run time. Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd